# How do I get the current data and time in the Alexa Node SDK?

Tags: javascript, date, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use have Alexa say "todays date is {data}" and the time is {time}" but I cant figure out how to do this. Basically how do I take a javascript timestamp (I'm using the Alexa Node SDK) and turn that into date and time text within lambda ?

Comment: have look into `momentjs` specifically `.humanize()`